# Extract text without extracting urls using regex?

Tags: regex

I extracted a lot of text from forum posts and now am filtering it. I'm using regex with the following pattern:

```
pattern = [A-Za-zćžđščČĆŽĐŠ0-9'\-]+|[\.]+|[\?]+|[\!]+|[\,\@\%\#\*\(\)\:]
```

and I get something like this:

```
'internetske', 'komunikacije', ',', 'te', 'njega', 'neovlašteno', 'isključili', '.', 'Uz', 'to', 'izvješće', 'Živkovića', '-', 'a', 'i'
```

However, I also have urls in this text which gets split into words as well. *I want text without urls.* I tried the following but it only unmatches h at the beginning of http:

```
pattern = (?!https?://)[A-Za-zćžđščČĆŽĐŠ0-9'\-]+|[\.]+|[\?]+|[\!]+|[\,\@\%\#\*\(\)\:]
```

I feel like this needs a simple tweak, but I'm slowly going crazy trying to figure out how to make an exception not match urls while matching the rest. You can assume that the urls have spaces around them.

Comment: I don't really know about making exceptions in regex, but since most URLs end by a ".something", you might be able to do it by excluding everything starting from http:// or https:// then ending by "the last dot + some letters" ; it's just a suggestion but hope this could help you a bit

Comment: you want the URLs to be extracted as a single word? I think you should just create a separate case for this in the regex.

Comment: Try `https?:\S+|[A-Za-zćžđščČĆŽĐŠ0-9'-]+|\.+|\?+|!+|[,@%#*():]`

Comment: I think I was not clear. I want url-free text.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the URLs to be extracted as a single word? 
I think you should just create a separate case for this in the regex.

Something like this:

```
(https?:\/\/\w+.\w+(?:\/[\w|\\-|#]+)|[A-Za-zćžđščČĆŽĐŠ0-9'\-]+|[\.]+|[\?]+|[\!]+|[\,\@\%\#\*\(\)\:])
```

https://regex101.com/r/3jWDeT/1/

Comment: I'm sorry, my wording was terrible. I want no urls in my final text. I want to extract words and other linguistic characters, without extracting urls at all.